# Next.js: How do you pass data to a route created dynamically

Tags: reactjs, next.js, nextjs-dynamic-routing

I have a component that is receiving data:

```
const ProductTile = ({ data }) => {
  let { productList } = data
  var [products] = productList
  var { products } = products;
  return (
    <div>
      <div className="p-10 grid grid-cols-1 sm:grid-cols-1 md:grid-cols-3 lg:grid-cols-3 xl:grid-cols-3 gap-5">

        {products.reduce((products, product) => products.find(x => x.productId === product.productId) ? products : [...products, product], []).map(({ colorCode, defaultColorCode, now, productId, productCode, productDescription, }, index) => {
            return (
              <Link key={`${productId}${index}`}
                href={{
                  pathname: '/s7-img-facade/[slug]',
                  query: { slug: productCode },
                }}
                passHref>
                  /* template */
              </Link>
            )
          })}
      </div>
    </div>
  )
}

export default ProductTile
```

It creates a grid of templates each wrapped in a `<Link>` component which is rendering a dynamic component;

`/s7-img-facade/[product]`

What I would like is for the dynamic component to have access to `products` object which is in the `ProductTile` .

I know that I can do a `getStaticProps` in the dynamic component to do another request but that seems redundant and not dry...

Any ideas how the dynamic component get access to the `products` object?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

You've got the right idea - you can pass additional properties in the `query` field, but you'll need to use `getServerSideProps` to extract those from the `query` param and pass it to the page component as props. Something like this:

```js
// pages/product.js
...
  <Link key={`${productId}${index}`}
    href={{
      pathname: '/s7-img-facade/[slug]',
      query: {
        description: productDescription, 
        slug: productCode
      },
    }}
    passHref
  >
    /* template */
  </Link>
...

// pages/s7-img-facase/[slug].js
export default function S7ImgFacasePage({ description }) {
  return <p>{ description }</p>
}

export const getServerSideProps = ({ params }) => {
  const description = { params }
  return {
    props: {
      description
    }
  }
}
```

So basically you pass it from the first page in params, read that in `getServerSideProps` of the second page, and then pass that as a prop to the second page component.

You mentioned `getStaticProps` - this won't work with static pages because `getStaticProps` is only run at build time so it won't know anything about the params you send at run time. If you need a fully static site, then you should consider passing it as a url parameter and reading it in `useEffect` or passing all possible pages through `getStaticPaths` and `getStaticProps` to generate all your static pages.